# Web app - Biometric system connection

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, web-applications, biometrics

I will be developing an application for a club where they will have visitors use biometric systems(finger print) or magnetic cards to mark their attendance.

This application is planned as a web app, made using PHP/MySQL/Javascript. It does a lot of other things as well.

What I wanted to find out is how is the interface between Biometric/Megnetic Card systems to a web app done?

I've never worked on this and am hoping if someone who has experience with this can throw some light on this as to how this could be accomplished. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Also, we will be hosting this application remotely. So we won't have physical access to the web-server.

(I'm afraid there's got to be some form of application installed on a pc that would interface with the hardware and probably makes calls to the web app. But, if there was a way to connect it to the web app directly, then the app would be easy to deploy to any location with minimal installation.)

Thanks! :)

Comment: Handling hardware needs proper "driver", PHP is not good at "metalbashing"; moreover, normally drivers need special OS assistance, so to say, and this means that at the best the driver must be installed since PHP can't have the kind of required "access" to the hw. Even other lang like C, normally you use a driver, or write a driver to be used from a normal user app. So there's no way: there must be a sw that handles the hw, and it can't be PHP directly. (PHP ext doing it can be programmed... in a more "low level" language like C, and you must deploy it too)...

Comment: @Dmin check if http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html helps

Answer (score 2):

How is the hardware connected?  Directly to the app server, or to a standalone box of some sort?  If it's a standalone box, then yes you'll have to have some kind of program on the box collect the data and send it to the web app.  If it's connected directly to the app server, then you need to write something that either polls the hardware or receives messages/events from the driver and DTRT wrt the web app.

Comment: The application will be hosted remotely, so we won't have physical access to the web server. I guess we'll need to use some sort of a software solution and have that interact with the webapp.

Comment: Yep.  I'd suggest a simple web service to take the data and write it to the database.  You might even be able to do it from a batch file using `curl` or something similar (if you don't like creating installers and such).

Comment: Neat, I didn't know you could to cURL from dos. :)

Answer (score 0):

There three type of communication channels are supported by the biometric machines. They are serial, TCP/IP and HTTP. In your case, you either need to implement TCP/IP or HTTP.

If your application is running the intranet, then you can implement the TCP/IP server application and host at a intranet system which is expected to write in a common database between the biometric application and your web-app.

If your application is hosted at the server, then you can implement the http server and associated the URL with the machine. For this you need buy the http api supported machines. Here is the [google search link](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1RLNS_enIN688IN688&q=web%20api%20for%20the%20biometric%20machines%20which%20can%20be%20integrated%20with%20website&oq=web%20api%20for%20the%20biometric%20machines%20which%20can%20be%20integrated%20with%20website&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20951.34896.0.35061.69.58.1.0.0.0.286.6829.0j32j9.41.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..27.21.3414...0j0i22i30k1j33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1j33i21k1.MS_RNx22XzQ) for finding such machines.